# How to make two columns of dataframe map type?

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, transform

How to make two columns of dataframe map type?
[image]

I want to create a map type with two columns of data frames

-----------------------------result ----------------------------------------------------------------

map
['account' -> 3 , 'word1' -> 2, 'word5' ->1 ......]

this is my code

```
keyword_f = df.filter(month(df['date']) >= 7) \
                    .filter(month(df['date']) <= 12) \
                    .filter(df['statistic_type'] == 'keyword_A') \
                    .groupby('word').agg(fn.sum('count'))
```

Answer (score 1):

After you groping by to the `word` and `count`, you can collect the result in this way.

```
df.groupBy().agg(map_from_arrays(collect_list('col1'), collect_list('col2')).alias('map')) \
  .show(10, False)

+------------------------+
|map                     |
+------------------------+
|[A -> 1, B -> 2, C -> 3]|
+------------------------+
```